# Invoking methods with drools

Tags: field, drools, rules

This is a beginner question with drools.  I have looked over the doc and code examples and still can't figure out what should be very simple to do.

In my when statement, I have a variable $servletRequest of type HttpServletRequest.  I know how to invoke a getter that doesn't take any input parameter, such as getCharacterEncoding.  I.e., this:

```
when
  ...
  HttpServletRequest( characterEncoding == "xxx" ) from $servletRequest
then
```

works.  However, I can't figure out how to invoke a getter that requires an input argument.  I.e., I would like to access the header "X-REQUESTED-PAGE" from my request, but the following doesn't work:

```
when
  ...
  HttpServletRequest( header["X-REQUESTED-PAGE"] == "xxx" ) from $servletRequest
then
```

It gives me an exception:

```
org.drools.RuntimeDroolsException: Exception executing predicate header["X-REQUESTED-PAGE"] == "xxx"
    at org.drools.rule.PredicateConstraint.isAllowed(PredicateConstraint.java:279)
...
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drools 5.5, this should work:

```
when
  ...
  HttpServletRequest( getHeader("X-REQUESTED-PAGE").equals("xxx") ) from $servletRequest
then
```

Comment: I love you and I love Stack Overflow. Thanks for the help.